# After graph-tool installation on mac I get ValueError: Namespace Gtk not available

Tags: python, anaconda, graph-tool, conda-forge

I have installed graph-tool using this line on mac 10.14:

```
conda create --name graphtool -c conda-forge graph-tool
```

However, when I try to use on of the example codes on graph-tool website I got an error message regarding gtk:

```
----> 1 from graph_tool.all import *
...
ValueError: Namespace Gtk not available
```

I have tried to install gtk3 using Homebrew (`brew install gtk+3`), but it doesn't seems to help and I still get the same error.

Anyone had the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need PyGObject https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html - this is current PyGTK package. It's available in homebrew as pygobject3.

Answer (score 0):

The initial (2019) builds of `graph-tool` on the `conda-forge` channel did not support drawing, since the `gtk3` package was not yet available.  In the meantime, that issue has been resolved, so new users will not encounter this error.